# How to implement parcelable for List<Long>

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass a List in my parcelable doing:

```
public class MetaDados implements Parcelable {

private List<Long> sizeImages;

public MetaDados(List<Long> sizeImages){
this.sizeImages = sizeImages;
}

public List<Long> getSizeImages() {
        return sizeImages;
    }

    public void setSizeImages(List<Long> sizeImages) {
        this.sizeImages = sizeImages;
    }

@Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
dest.writeList(sizeImages);
}

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MetaDados> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MetaDados>() {
        @Override
        public MetaDados createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MetaDados(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MetaDados[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MetaDados[size];
        }
    };

private MetaDados(Parcel in) {
//HERE IS THE PROBLEM, I'VE tried this:

sizeImages = in.readList(sizeImages, Long.class.getClassLoader());

//but what i got: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to List<Long>
}
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
sizeImages = new ArrayList<Long>(); // or any other type of List
in.readList(sizeImages, null);
```

The [Android documentation for `Parcel.readList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readList%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) says:

> Read into an existing List object from the parcel

and thus, you need to first create the `List`.