# How to implement parcelable for List<Integer> in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make Parcelable of below class

```
data class Movie(
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    @Expose
    var popularity: Double,

    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    @Expose
    var voteCount: Int,

    @SerializedName("video")
    @Expose
    var video: Boolean,

    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    var posterPath: String?,

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: Int,

    @SerializedName("adult")
    @Expose
    var adult: Boolean,

    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    @Expose
    var backdropPath: String?,

    @SerializedName("original_language")
    @Expose
    var originalLanguage: String?,

    @SerializedName("original_title")
    @Expose
    var originalTitle: String?,

    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    @Expose
    var genreIds: List<Integer>,

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    var title: String?,

    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    @Expose
    var voteAverage: Double,

    @SerializedName("overview")
    @Expose
    var overview: String?,

    @SerializedName("release_date")
    @Expose
    var releaseDate: String?
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readInt(),
        parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readInt(),
        parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        TODO("genreIds"),   <-------------- Which is generated by "Android Parcelable code generator" plugin
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString()
    ) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeDouble(popularity)
        parcel.writeInt(voteCount)
        parcel.writeByte(if (video) 1 else 0)
        parcel.writeString(posterPath)
        parcel.writeInt(id)
        parcel.writeByte(if (adult) 1 else 0)
        parcel.writeString(backdropPath)
        parcel.writeString(originalLanguage)
        parcel.writeString(originalTitle)
        parcel.writeString(title)
        parcel.writeDouble(voteAverage)
        parcel.writeString(overview)
        parcel.writeString(releaseDate)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Movie> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Movie {
            return Movie(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Movie?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

I was getting an error so I have found solution from this website [How to implement parcelable for List<Long>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774236/how-to-implement-parcelable-for-listlong)

and done like below

```
parcel.readList("genreIds",null),
```

but I am still getting an error like

[image]

And also by follwing this page
[How to parcel List<Int> with kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371013/how-to-parcel-listint-with-kotlin)
I have added extension functions like below

```
fun Parcel.writeIntList(input:List<Int>) {
    writeInt(input.size) // Save number of elements.
    input.forEach(this::writeInt) // Save each element.
}

fun Parcel.createIntList() : List<Int> {
    val size = readInt()
    val output = ArrayList<Int>(size)
    for (i in 0 until size) {
        output.add(readInt())
    }
    return output
}
```

Hi @Eugen Pechanec first of all thank you so much for your help, as per you suggestion I have done **Int** instead of **Integer** but in readArrayList still I am getting an error

[image]

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371013/how-to-parcel-listint-with-kotlin

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudElsakka but it does not help me :(

Comment: Kotlin doesn't have `Integer`. Use `Int`. Here: `var genreIds: List<Integer>`

Comment: You also forgot to write the list in `writeToParcel`, careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @ Eugen Pechanec & @Networks I found solution which is below,

```
 data class Movie(
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    @Expose
    var popularity: Double,

    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    @Expose
    var voteCount: Int,

    @SerializedName("video")
    @Expose
    var video: Boolean,

    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    var posterPath: String?,

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: Int,

    @SerializedName("adult")
    @Expose
    var adult: Boolean,

    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    @Expose
    var backdropPath: String?,

    @SerializedName("original_language")
    @Expose
    var originalLanguage: String?,

    @SerializedName("original_title")
    @Expose
    var originalTitle: String?,

    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    @Ignore
    var genreIds: List<Int>,

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    var title: String?,

    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    @Expose
    var voteAverage: Double,

    @SerializedName("overview")
    @Expose
    var overview: String?,

    @SerializedName("release_date")
    @Expose
    var releaseDate: String?
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readInt(),
        parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readInt(),
        parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.createIntList(),  //<-------------------------- change here
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString()
    )
    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeDouble(popularity)
        parcel.writeInt(voteCount)
        parcel.writeByte(if (video) 1 else 0)
        parcel.writeString(posterPath)
        parcel.writeInt(id)
        parcel.writeByte(if (adult) 1 else 0)
        parcel.writeString(backdropPath)
        parcel.writeString(originalLanguage)
        parcel.writeString(originalTitle)
        parcel.writeIntList(genreIds) //<-------------------------- change here
        parcel.writeString(title)
        parcel.writeDouble(voteAverage)
        parcel.writeString(overview)
        parcel.writeString(releaseDate)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Movie> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Movie {
            return Movie(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Movie?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }


    }
}


            fun Parcel.createIntList(): List<Int> {
                val size = readInt()
                val output = ArrayList<Int>(size)
                for (i in 0 until size) {
                    output.add(readInt())
                }
                return output
            }

            fun Parcel.writeIntList(input:List<Int>) {
                writeInt(input.size) // Save number of elements.
                return input.forEach(this::writeInt) // Save each element.
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Move `createIntList()` and writeIntList outside the scope of your Movie class like below:

```
package com.acs.mtnprodapp.data.local.entity

import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class Movie(
        @SerializedName("popularity")
        @Expose
        var popularity: Double,

        @SerializedName("vote_count")
        @Expose
        var voteCount: Int,

        @SerializedName("video")
        @Expose
        var video: Boolean,

        @SerializedName("poster_path")
        @Expose
        var posterPath: String?,

        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        var id: Int,

        @SerializedName("adult")
        @Expose
        var adult: Boolean,

        @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
        @Expose
        var backdropPath: String?,

        @SerializedName("original_language")
        @Expose
        var originalLanguage: String?,

        @SerializedName("original_title")
        @Expose
        var originalTitle: String?,

        @SerializedName("genre_ids")
        @Expose
        var genreIds: List<Int>,

        @SerializedName("title")
        @Expose
        var title: String?,

        @SerializedName("vote_average")
        @Expose
        var voteAverage: Double,

        @SerializedName("overview")
        @Expose
        var overview: String?,

        @SerializedName("release_date")
        @Expose
        var releaseDate: String?
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readDouble(),
            parcel.readInt(),
            parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readInt(),
            parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.createIntList(),
    parcel.readString(),
    parcel.readDouble(),
    parcel.readString(),
    parcel.readString()
    ) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeDouble(popularity)
        parcel.writeInt(voteCount)
        parcel.writeByte(if (video) 1 else 0)
        parcel.writeString(posterPath)
        parcel.writeInt(id)
        parcel.writeIntList(genreIds)
        parcel.writeByte(if (adult) 1 else 0)
        parcel.writeString(backdropPath)
        parcel.writeString(originalLanguage)
        parcel.writeString(originalTitle)
        parcel.writeString(title)
        parcel.writeDouble(voteAverage)
        parcel.writeString(overview)
        parcel.writeString(releaseDate)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Movie> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Movie {
            return Movie(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Movie?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }

    //move from here
}

//to here
fun Parcel.writeIntList(input:List<Int>) {
    writeInt(input.size) // Save number of elements.
    input.forEach(this::writeInt) // Save each element.
}

fun Parcel.createIntList() : List<Int> {
    val size = readInt()
    val output = ArrayList<Int>(size)
    for (i in 0 until size) {
        output.add(readInt())
    }
    return output
}
```

This would make the methods available to other class as well

Comment: I have tried that first but in that I am getting an error as i have shown in last picture " Can not access createIntList....."

Comment: You need to move the methods out of the class like so: `class Movie{} // place them here`. Don't worry methods without classes are allowed in Kotlin. You can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013996/why-is-possible-to-write-a-function-outside-a-class-in-kotlin

Answer (score -1):

as my first comment you could convert your list of integers to List of int 
as

```
class Movie(
...
    var genreIds: List<Int>,
..)
```

so , in case you want to save movie object as Json  i recommend using Serializable
it doesn't required any implementation method

```
data class Movie(


    var originalLanguage: String?,

    var originalTitle: String?,


    var genreIds: List<Integer>,


    var title: String?,


    var voteAverage: Double,

    var overview: String?,

    var releaseDate: String?
) : Serializable
```

and you could save it as following

```
        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences.Editor = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
        val json = gson.toJson(YOUR_OBJECT)
        sharedPref.putString(Constants.MOVIE, json)
        sharedPref.commit()
```

and get it

```
        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val json = sharedPref.getString(Constants.MOVIE, null)
        if(json != null) {
            return gson.fromJson(json, Movie::class.java)
        } else {
            return null
        }
```

Comment: Serialization dumps all its implicit baggage onto you. Every time you compile the app the serialization process may change (the compiler is in charge). You're not required to do anything when you add or remove fields but it will alter the byte representation of the class and fail on deserialization. On the other hand you have `Parcelable` which forces you to take care of it. And is also more performant because it doesn't use introspection - because you had to wrote the serialization code yourself. Final note, `Serializable` has nothing to do with Gson, at all.